# Load .epub content to UIWebview with only Horizontal scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, horizontal-scrolling, epub

Currently I'm working on to display Epub content in `UIWebview`. [From this link I have downloaded one sample app for Epub](http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html) which fulfills all my needs except one thing that is, need to scroll the webview horizontally instead of vertical scroll. Anyone please help me out to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that mean you need to make a pagination for the html content .. this done by some java script functions .. there is already uploaded open source files to do this .. just google it :).

Comment: :thanks for your reply.Past two days i explored about this but,i didn't get anything useful.Please give me some useful links to do this...

Comment: check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/epub-tools/source/browse/#svn/trunk/epubtools/epubjs)

Comment: hi @iphonecool have you solved your problem actually I am facing the same please help me...