# How to Load .ePub content in UIWebview with pagination

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, epub, jquery-pagination

I want to show all the contents from .ePub file to UIWebview with pagination(horizontal scrolling). For that i need to find out total content size that,each chapter contains, page size..

I'm not at all clear about how/where should i start. I don't know how to use **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** to call the methods. Where should i write the function definition which is called using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. Please anyone give me a step by step procedure for UIWebview pagination. There may be same question but i didn't get any clear explanation.

Explain me Step by step JQuery procedure

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We aren't here to do your work for you. Go and try something yourself and then post specific questions relating to that. You were given some pointers to code for this in the other question you asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563145/load-epub-content-to-uiwebview-with-only-horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: @NickBull:I'm very new to JQuery.so only i'm asking lengthy question.Please provide some guidens to start working uiwebview pagination.Thank you

Comment: You may be new at JQuery, but that doesn't stop you being able to use the search function of Stack Overflow and Google. There are lots of tutorials regarding JQuery. If you are new to it, then start off slowly and build up your knowledge - don't just leap in and try to do something so difficult.

Comment: @NickBull:I downloaded one application for Epubreader which satisfies all my requirements(webview pagination).But, in that application i put .epub file with images and texts. Images getting cut off. i don't know how to solve this.NickBull please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find good example of parsing and displaying ePub [here](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader). It does not use JQuery, only javascript.